# How to use both IAutoMapOverride<Base> and IgnoreBase<Base>

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I have a set of entities which all derive from ModelBase. This includes things like Id,CreatedOn,LastModified.

I want to be able to use DynamicUpdate with all the mappings. How do I do this?

I've tried, without success, adding `.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<MyAutoMapOverrides>()` where my override is simply:

```
public class MyAutoMapOverrides : IAutoMappingOverride<Model.ModelBase>
{
   public void Override(FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<Model.ModelBase> mapping)
   {
      mapping.DynamicUpdate();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And 30 more minutes of searching turns up the answer:
`.Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DynamicUpdate.AlwaysTrue())`

This, however, breaks my event handlers that set LastModified and CreatedOn.  Due to that, I'll probably just stick with updating all properties.